# How To handle cookies in a crawler

Tags: java, http, http-headers, jsoup, web-crawler

I am building a webcrawler ( a tiny one). Few sites like [NYTIMES](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/06/08/us/politics/obama-plans-steps-to-ease-student-debt.html?rref=politics) checks for cookies whenever we visit them. It seems they first check cookie, if not available it sets it. If it goes wrong, it redirects to Login Page.

Now, how this behavior can be handled using programming and prevent redirection.

Answer (score 0):

**General Answer:**
Cookies are used for a number of different purposes, so there's no one-size-fits-all solution that you can use for a crawler. Most sites use cookies as a key component of their user identification schemes, and if you mess with those, the site might not identify your crawler for what it is. This is not preferred. If you want more info on sending cookie data, though, you can read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie. The important line in the HTTP request is:

```
Cookie: name=value; name2=value2
```

---

**Specific Answer:**
From what I know of the NY Times site, they require a subscription in order to read their material, so their cookies are probably required for authentication, and should not be spoofed by a crawler.